# Django. Переход в редактор профиля после регистрации пользователя

Tags: python, django, django-model, регистрация, редактор

Ситуация такая. Человек Менеджер должен зарегистрировать юзера, а после нажатия на регистрацию перейти в редактор этого юзера заполнить оставшиеся поля и сохранить. У меня же можно редактировать профиль только того кто авторизован на сайте, то есть самого менеджера.

views.py

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """
    Представление для редактирования профиля 
    """
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm
    template_name = 'system/profile_edit.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user.profile

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = f'Редактирование профиля пользователя: {self.request.user.username}'
        if self.request.POST:
            context['user_form'] = UserUpdateForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.request.user)
        else:
            context['user_form'] = UserUpdateForm(instance=self.request.user)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        user_form = context['user_form']
        with transaction.atomic():
            if all([form.is_valid(), user_form.is_valid()]):
                user_form.save()
                form.save()
            else:
                context.update({'user_form': user_form})
                return self.render_to_response(context)
        return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('profile_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

forms.py

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Форма обновления данных пользователя
    """

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','first_name', 'last_name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Обновление стилей формы под bootstrap
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'autocomplete': 'off'
            })

    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Проверка email на уникальность
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email адрес должен быть уникальным')
        return email



class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Форма обновления данных профиля пользователя
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('patronymic','birth_date', 'bio',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Обновление стилей формы обновления
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control',
                'autocomplete': 'off'
            })
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)   
    patronymic = models.CharField('Отчество',max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) 
    group_manager = models.ForeignKey(StudentsGroup, related_name='teacher', verbose_name='Руководит группой', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    lessons = models.ManyToManyField(Lessons, related_name='teachers', verbose_name='Ведет предметы')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,verbose_name='Информация о себе')
    birth_date = models.DateField(
    null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата рождения')    
    position = models.CharField('Должность', max_length=99)
    
    class Meta:
        """
        Сортировка, название таблицы в базе данных
        """
        db_table = 'app_profiles'
        ordering = ('user',)
        verbose_name = 'Профиль'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Профили'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Сохранение полей модели при их отсутствии заполнения
        """
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = unique_slugify(self, self.user.username)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Возвращение строки
        """
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Ссылка на профиль
        """
        return reverse('profile_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

urls.py

```
path('user/edit/', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='profile_edit'),
path('user/<str:slug>/', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile_detail'),    
path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
```

Я добавил этот код:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import addTeachers


def add_teachers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addTeachers(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_teachers')
    else:
        form = addTeachers()
    return render(request, 'system/add_teachers.html', {'form': form})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью slug, теперь после регистрации сразу же переходит на страницу заполнения формы профиля

```
 return redirect('edit_profile', slug=user.profile.slug)
```